# Convolution of $e^{-|t|}$ and a Band-pass

Tags: exponential-function, absolute-value, convolution

Can someone explain how you would solve this convolution:

$$\sigma(t)=\text{ Heaviside}-\text{Function}$$
$$f(t)=e^{-|t|}$$
$$g(t)=\sigma(t+T)-\sigma(t-T)$$

$$(f*g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\tau|}(\sigma(t-\tau+T)-\sigma(t-\tau-T)) d\tau$$

**Is this method correct:**

1) defining exp-function Piece-wise:

$$ 
(f*g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{\tau}(\sigma(t-\tau+T)-\sigma(t-\tau-T))d\tau+ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\tau}(\sigma(t-\tau+T)-\sigma(t-\tau-T)) d\tau
$$

what would be the next steps?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}(f*g)(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\tau|}(\sigma(t-\tau+T)-\sigma(t-\tau-T)) d\tau\\
&=\int_{t-\tau-T}^{t-\tau+T}e^{-|\tau|}d\tau
\end{align}$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: thanks, i got the idea ;) . will give a try